# How to know when it's a migraine, tension, cluster, sinus, or rebound headache?

Tags: cluster-headache, rebound-headache, sinus-headache, beta-blockers

How to know when it's a migraine, tension, cluster, sinus, or rebound headache?

I've always thought I've had migraines and have been treated for such using daily beta-blockers. My symptoms have been extreme sensitivity to light, noise, smell, seeing auras, and feeling a sense of throbbing/pounding in my head. On an "as needed" basis, I used Excedrin Migraine, but I'm worried that triggers rebound-headaches.

**What are the symptoms of cluster, tension, sinus, & rebound headaches? How do you adequately distinguish between them? Do beta-blockers work for all of them?**

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, I came across this chart in a magazine like 20 minutes after reading your question!! It explains the many differences (and some similarities) between migraine, tension, and cluster headaches. *(I apologize for the bluriness of the picture. Additionally, I apolgozie it doesn't also compare sinus headaches, but those are often distinguished by sinus congestion and feeling pressure in the front of your face -- please see* http://www.webmd.com/migraines-headaches/guide/sinus-headaches*).*

[image]

P.s. I'm also unsure about the effectiveness of beta-blockers. I tried researching, but only found it referenced as a treatment for migraines (and assummingly rebound headaches). Good luck!